# How to select a part of a range, which is output of a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, excel-365

I seem to be really bad at writing readable titles :-)

Here's the situation:
I have a list of names and values, and I would like to calculate the sum of the values, corresponding to every name:

```
Name  Value
   a      1
   b      2
   a      3
   c      4
   a      5
   b      6
   c      7
```

This looks really simple:

```
for 'a' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8)
for 'b' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,A3,$B$2:$B$8)
for 'c' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,A4,$B$2:$B$8)
```

Oops, that's wrong, because A4 does not contain 'c', it contains 'a' again.

No sweat: we can use the `UNIQUE()` formula, which puts the values 'a', 'b' and 'c' in column F (`=UNIQUE(A2:A8)`).
Once we have this, we can easily use this formula:

```
for 'a' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,F2,$B$2:$B$8)
for 'b' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,F3,$B$2:$B$8)
for 'c' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,F4,$B$2:$B$8)
```

This is correct, but it means that I must use the F column as a reference.
I don't want that, I want something like:

```
for 'a' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,UNIQUE(A2:A8).getElement(1),$B$2:$B$8)
for 'b' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,UNIQUE(A2:A8).getElement(2),$B$2:$B$8)
for 'c' : =SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,UNIQUE(A2:A8).getElement(3),$B$2:$B$8)
```

This, obviously, makes no sense, as `getElement()` does not exist.
How can I access a part of a `UNIQUE()` result?

This is how my Excel sheet looks like:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: would it be better to use a pivot table, that way the sumation of the values would be handled automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if you want two columns or not, but with ms365:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(A2:A8),SUMIF(A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8),B2:B8))
```

---

And to answer the part on the '.GetElement', I'd say that `INDEX()` is a very good translation and allows you to *slice* into an array and pick any of your liking. I don't think it's your goal, but if say you are interested in only the 2nd row of the whole array you can use: `=INDEX(PreviousFormula, 2, 0)`. The '0' will ensure that we return all column that make up that row and can be left out if the array is only made of a single column in the first place.

Comment: You are using `SUMIF(A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8),B2:B8)` which returns a range of three cells. Is there a way to get only one of those cells?

Comment: @Dominique, I just wrote an update which might be helpfull in that regard? Let me know.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, this is phenomenal, I have learnt a great technique from your one of the solution of FILTERXML, and i keep using it whenever required. Sorry though its not related to the post, but i have learnt from your solutions a lot. Thank you Sir's